# unable to load libtidy.dylib

Tags: ruby, rubygems, macports, tidy

I'm trying to run on my mac os 10.6 a Ruby script that apparently requires libtidy.

I spent an hour trying to find an information on how to get libtidy installed.

'gem install tidy' didn't help

I'm amazed that I was unable to find the answers in google :/

Comment: Just installed it. Worked like a charm. What error are you getting? I am on mac 10.6, ruby 1.8.7 (rvm)

Comment: and by apt-cache you mean, you want to search available packages in macports?

Comment: i solved the problem with libtidy, but still didn't manage to install apt-cache properly..

zengr - here are the details of apt-cache problems:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969470/cant-install-apt-on-macports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved it:

fink install tiny-dev

locate libtidy.dylib

cp /.../libtidy.dylib /..path of ruby../..