# can't install apt on macports

Tags: macos, macports

THe following error appears

```
:info:build Compiling contrib/hashes.cc to /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_sysutils_apt/work/apt-0.5.27/build/obj/apt-pkg/hashes.opic
:info:build Compiling depcache.cc to /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_sysutils_apt/work/apt-0.5.27/build/obj/apt-pkg/depcache.opic
:info:build contrib/hashes.cc: In member function 'bool Hashes::AddFD(int, long unsigned int)':
:info:build contrib/hashes.cc:33: error: expected primary-expression before '?' token
:info:build contrib/hashes.cc:33: error: expected `:' before ')' token
:info:build contrib/hashes.cc:33: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
:info:build contrib/hashes.cc:34: error: expected primary-expression before '?' token
:info:build contrib/hashes.cc:34: error: expected `:' before ')' token
:info:build contrib/hashes.cc:34: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
:info:build gnumake[2]: *** [/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_sysutils_apt/work/apt-0.5.27/build/obj/apt-pkg/hashes.opic] Error 1
:info:build gnumake[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
:info:build contrib/md5.cc: In member function 'bool MD5Summation::AddFD(int, long unsigned int)':
:info:build contrib/md5.cc:302: error: expected primary-expression before '?' token
:info:build contrib/md5.cc:302: error: expected `:' before ')' token
:info:build contrib/md5.cc:302: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
:info:build contrib/md5.cc:303: error: expected primary-expression before '?' token
:info:build contrib/md5.cc:303: error: expected `:' before ')' token
:info:build contrib/md5.cc:303: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
:info:build contrib/sha1.cc: In member function 'bool SHA1Summation::AddFD(int, long unsigned int)':
:info:build contrib/sha1.cc:348: error: expected primary-expression before '?' token
:info:build contrib/sha1.cc:348: error: expected `:' before ')' token
:info:build contrib/sha1.cc:348: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
:info:build contrib/sha1.cc:349: error: expected primary-expression before '?' token
:info:build contrib/sha1.cc:349: error: expected `:' before ')' token
:info:build contrib/sha1.cc:349: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
:info:build gnumake[2]: *** [/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_sysutils_apt/work/apt-0.5.27/build/obj/apt-pkg/md5.opic] Error 1
:info:build gnumake[2]: *** [/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_sysutils_apt/work/apt-0.5.27/build/obj/apt-pkg/sha1.opic] Error 1
:info:build gnumake[1]: *** [all] Error 2
:info:build gnumake: *** [all] Error 2
:info:build shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_sysutils_apt/work/apt-0.5.27/build" && /usr/bin/gnumake -j2 all " returned error 2
:error:build Target org.macports.build returned: shell command failed
:debug:build Backtrace: shell command failed
    while executing
"command_exec build"
    (procedure "portbuild::build_main" line 8)
    invoked from within
"$procedure $targetname"
:info:build Warning: the following items did not execute (for apt): org.macports.activate org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
:notice:build Log for apt is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_sysutils_apt/main.log
```

I'm using Mac OS 10.6. Any idea?